# Amazon Athena - Converting Timestamp to Date?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Looking at the [Date/Time Athena documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html), I don't see a function to do this, which surprises me. The closest I see is `date_trunc('week', timestamp)` but that results in something like `2017-07-09 00:00:00.000` while I would like the format to be `2017-07-09`

Is there an easy function to convert a timestamp to a date?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reason for not having a conversion function is, that this can be achieved with a type cast.

So a converting query would look like this:

```
select DATE(current_timestamp)
```

Comment: or `CAST(some_timestamp AS DATE)`

Comment: try this `select CAST(from_unixtime(1633431230) AS DATE) ;`

Comment: Or if you want date with time: `select CAST(from_unixtime(1633431230) AS timestamp)`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have an ISO DateTime format you can use the following syntax:

```
select date(from_iso8601_timestamp(COLUMN_NAME)) FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```