# Get current date with time 00:00:00/23:59:59

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

:)

I'm running queries on AWS Athena and want to check whether a certain datetime (Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second) is within the current date's 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 time interval. I checked presto's documentation, but can not figure out how to pull that off in presto.

Does anyone have an idea on how this could be achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292219/amazon-athena-converting-timestamp-to-date

Comment: _"the current date's 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 time interval"_? You mean, today?

Comment: @NicholasHunter Yes. How can I dynamically check whether a datetime is between two different days (or on the same day) where the first day has Hour-Minute-Second set to 00:00:00 and the other day set to 23:59:59

Comment: Have you tried WHERE DATE([AWS Time stamp]) = DATE([Comparison Date])?

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
select mydate >= date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) and mydate < date_trunc('day', current_timestamp+interval '1' day)
```

see the `date_trunc` docs: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html